# how does nginx decide what is allowed and what is forbidden?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I had the following simple default website:

server {

```
listen 80;
listen 192.168.1.13;
listen 10.8.0.21;
#listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6


index index.html index.htm;

server_name docs;

location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
}

}
```

Requsts like:

`curl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" http://192.168.1.13`

were refused with error 403, but requests to  `curl --header "X-MyHeader: 123" http://10.8.0.21` were responded.

When I changed the location directive to:

```
location / {
            allow 192.168.1.0/24
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
```

Requests to `http://192.168.1.13` were answered properly. Is it always the case that one needs to `allow` IP ranges with Ngnix?

Comment: What's in the error log ?

Comment: Nginx typically allows anything that isn't denied by default.  I've only had to be explicit when I want to allow only from certain hosts and deny everything else.